# Cannot retrieve repository from channel "rhel-x86_64-server-6"

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, rhel6

I have a red hat satellite 5.7 with subscribed servers to the rhn under a 3.4 rhev installation and I just created a VM with RHEL 6.6, subscribed it with satellite to the rhn, configured the channels in the satellite console, did the check using `rhn_check` but when trying a `yum update` I get an error that yum cannot get the repository metadata (repomd.xml) for channel: rhel-x86_64-server-6.
I have other servers that already existed before me and work well with yum.
I tried disabling updates in `/etc/yum.repos.d/rhel-source.repo` as checking other posts like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/96977/why-is-yum-not-working-properly) or checking date and cleaning metadata as per [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/742253/issue-when-trying-to-run-command-yum-update-cannot-retrieve-repository-metadat) but got no luck.
What am I missing?
My repo file looks like this:

```
[rhel-source]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - Source
baseurl=ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/$releasever/en/os/SRPMS/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release

[rhel-source-beta]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever Beta - $basearch - Source
baseurl=ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/beta/$releasever/en/os/SRPMS/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-beta,file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
```

Answer (score 0):

your repo file only has rhel-source and rhel-source-beta defined

It needs an entry for rhel-x86_64-server-6 so it can find the repodata xml file